# Subtract values within group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
set.seed(42)
ID <- sample(1:15, 100, replace = TRUE)
value <- sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(ID, value)
```

I want to group by ID, and create a new column where each value is subtracted from all others within the group.

Like sum add all of these values into a single column, how do I subtract?

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
# what's the - equivalent! 
  mutate(value_c = sub(value))
```

Thanks

J

Comment: Can you create an example of, say, 10 rows and show the expected output based on that example?

Comment: What do you mean by substracted? -1 * sum()?? Why are you trying to use the `sub` function from the `grep` family??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its a somewhat odd calculation, but slightly to my own surprise, the following seems to do what you explain:

```r
set.seed(42)
ID <- sample(1:15, 100, replace = TRUE)
value <- sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(ID, value)

d %>% group_by( ID ) %>%
    mutate(
        value_c = value*2 - sum(value)
    ) %>%
    arrange( ID ) %>%
    head( n=20 )
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID value value_c
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     1     1     -12
 2     1     1     -12
 3     1     4      -6
 4     1     1     -12
 5     1     1     -12
 6     1     2     -10
 7     1     4      -6
 8     2     4     -21
 9     2     3     -23
10     2     3     -23
11     2     2     -25
12     2     1     -27
13     2     1     -27
14     2     3     -23
15     2     3     -23
16     2     1     -27
17     2     4     -21
18     2     4     -21
19     3     4      -8
20     3     4      -8
```

You multiply value by 2 because its going to be in the sum() anyway, which you didn't want, so adding it back on the left side takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  d,
  value_c = 2*value - ave(value,ID,FUN = sum)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, value_c := 2 * value - sum(value), ID]
```